# IE10 Select option indexing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Inherited some Javascript code (which is paraphrased in the Fiddle for ease of reproduction), which is filtering Select Options based on a selection in a previous Select.

When the page loads, a clone of the Select is made to hold the original values of the 2nd Select element.

When the user makes a Selection in Select element 1, Select element 2 is restored with the original values (as the user might make a different selection in element 1), and then it filters the list.

When the user makes a selection in Select 2, we remove the "Select..." element from the list... But In IE10 the selected element then becomes the option below it.

This *only* happens in IE10 (IE8/9/11 are all ok, as are latest versions of Chrome and FF)

It looks like an issue with the .clone() element being restored and the "Select..." option being removed.

[Here's a fiddle to check it](https://jsfiddle.net/jdunner/sLjn6t6x/1/)...

```
cloneModel = $("#model").clone();           

$("#make").change(function(){                                   
            restoreModels();                
            removeNoOption("#make");                
            $("#make").hide();
            $("#make").show();              
            filterModels($("#make option:selected").val()); 
            $("#model").show();             
        })          
function modelChange(){
            removeNoOption("#model");               
            $("#model").hide();
            $("#model").show(); 
        }


        function removeNoOption(element){           
            $(element + " option").each(function(){     
                if($(this).val() == "-"){
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            })
        }           
        function restoreModels(){
            $("#model").unbind();               
            $("#model").replaceWith(cloneModel);
            cloneModel = $("#model").clone();
            $("#model").change(modelChange);
            $("#model").hide();
        }

        function filterModels(make){
            $.each(models, function(key, value) {                   
                if(make != value.make){
                    $("#model option[value='"+value.model+"']").remove();   
                }

            });
        }
```

Anyone ever seen this before or know what could be happening?

Comment: what version of jQuery are you running? 1.5.0 by chance? https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: 1.6.2 in the application and 1.12.0 in the fiddle... So doesn't see version dependent.  I should add, moving the "removeNoOption("#model")" below the hide and show prevents the problem from happening.